# Get tableView from custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem iterating over custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`'s superviews to get its ancestor `tableView` but it returns nil and does not reach `tableView` at all. This solution works with `tableView` cell though.

Please note that I use custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView with Nib for sectionHeader or footer.

This is my code to get super view:

```
var parentView = self.superview

while (parentView != nil && !(parentView is T)) {
      parentView = parentView?.superview
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was iterating the custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView's` superviews when tableView not assigned itself to header view. So I override `didMoveToSuperview()` method in my class and my problem is gone.